# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Dropdown Menu Links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that is baffling me. The hamburger menu opens just fine and the dropdown list opens fine too but the links within the dropdown is not clickable.  When I click on it, it just closes again. the behavior is the same for desktop and mobile. I got the code from a blogger's tutorial.  Here's my link which has the blogger's stock code. The bootstrap the blogger was using is version is 4.2 but I also tried it with version 4.4 to no avail.

[Navbar menu link](http://m.shastinahomes.com/test.asp)
Click on the hamburger menu and then click on Category to open the dropdown menu.  I have a link called TEST LINK which is a valid link but it does not work.

Comment: Make sure you have imported all the bootstrap css and scripts. After that also make sure that the links have path to go to certain page. Otherwise it would just show a '#' symbol within your URL and nothing will happen.

Comment: Thank you Rohan.  I have replied to my own question with the solution. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If found that the  data-toggle="dropdown" is located in the wrong place. I moved it from the list tag to the anchor tag.  I also added specific IDs and labels for each of the dropdowns so that they work independently.